# Docker Cannot Start a Container Because of bash

Tags: docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm having a Docker image which looks like below when inspected.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:e11214d50ae2bf3ec1f97171a35d1164a04198bc879284a7b4bef4600272f978",
        "RepoTags": [
            "joesan/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation-run:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
            "joesan/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation-run:latest",
            "remote-repository-name:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
            "remote-repository-name:latest",
            "run:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
            "run:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [],
        "Parent": "sha256:5fffbc0f10de417e3bee965179c587f4f624f95c791b7cf83f11fe530de1f167",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2022-05-31T20:06:34.723768648Z",
        "Container": "158899e129f70bf77de8e3acf3b601b68b8673634dc946886914881e7cd7bbf2",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "158899e129f7",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "1001:0",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
                "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
                "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_VERSION=jdk-13.0.2+8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk",
                "LOG_DIR=/opt/docker/logs"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD []"
            ],
            "Image": "sha256:5fffbc0f10de417e3bee965179c587f4f624f95c791b7cf83f11fe530de1f167",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/docker/logs": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/docker",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/opt/docker/bin/run"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "MAINTAINER": "https://github.com/joesan"
            }
        },
        "DockerVersion": "20.10.16",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "1001:0",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
                "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
                "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
                "JAVA_VERSION=jdk-13.0.2+8",
                "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk",
                "LOG_DIR=/opt/docker/logs"
            ],
            "Cmd": [],
            "Image": "sha256:5fffbc0f10de417e3bee965179c587f4f624f95c791b7cf83f11fe530de1f167",
            "Volumes": {
                "/opt/docker/logs": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/opt/docker",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/opt/docker/bin/run"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "MAINTAINER": "https://github.com/joesan"
            }
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 283832166,
        "VirtualSize": 283832166,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e575a82f236695190a93d6c6d88ecfdf6d1ce9212d3d957dcf843e49a8300c46/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cb5e202b3311e93d6cd31ec469409e196b6c4a04e9d05419d9f53a7f0a677ca2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ea02909e4fd285f96af92de7a272f8ed7e7c1cebbeb43260c6a0bed77c1ccea4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/22c356c32c089c7e4f9e46cf86bb862c239ecc4308f44ac0ebba0f0b54c475f8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/307b78517367431d93218f6b7721d1a1dff642a4c4a9223aa8f2c78203f4de32/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d5d489df9f5b1df0fa22913bdc26ec7769fa2e7c31120ce2ace704a559a24975/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ceb258d847a218493b90d9bf8784bae782dce940f8d77a5d03cffd3ca35cb0c9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9103770fe966d570652142b356128392c51e2085665bcf45e2a891788cf1a608/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d6020a197bad3f7353033b65b9dc892493a1b88e155ed696f5d4cab523162c32/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ca9cfd6aeb4b6fba2c2b6febc7495120f78432ed6676a50268e3b551ce78a2f/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ca9cfd6aeb4b6fba2c2b6febc7495120f78432ed6676a50268e3b551ce78a2f/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ca9cfd6aeb4b6fba2c2b6febc7495120f78432ed6676a50268e3b551ce78a2f/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:50644c29ef5a27c9a40c393a73ece2479de78325cae7d762ef3cdc19bf42dd0a",
                "sha256:e9bf0d233b4aa9356e06c8bafe04d6fa26dca57519d7a1f7381fa1e81d851057",
                "sha256:1c9d4daf65688a60e21d20a152f77efea692008781dd2f3cf2f65a060ea1c525",
                "sha256:ed502be72f7430e3cd899e2e69493a9a8602dccf7937e8bd28a65035cfaf8e14",
                "sha256:d5a672bd7d34f9d7d0e50906aa6e9b1738d70b8848bc64b7d80cf586076364e3",
                "sha256:c84750f54e0212ea00b3e3acc327dac57829b5b738cc989dd3f42dfc751d3707",
                "sha256:6f91304b15347950dd8a555192151d3c08e77536a7c1f5d8c8440d137dadb9aa",
                "sha256:76815c495bd4f1dd92e1621ab6a49172c97c874f8403c5b76b0d8df672ea5ace",
                "sha256:147ac82a72dc269fba0031ec096949d5343739815c5cf2aa020c330fe2f2fa3a",
                "sha256:82b2748702ee0e20d1f419d245f75798ec13046d8994b0046f78a4152e7fcfde"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "2022-05-31T22:10:55.894269298+02:00"
        }
    }
]
```

This is a generated Docker image using the sbt-native-packager as I'm having a Scala project and using sbt as the build tool. I was now trying to run this Docker image as below:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/Private/ml-projects/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation$ docker run --rm -it joesan/housing-price-prediction-data-preparation-run:latest
env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory
```

Here is my build.sbt:

```
lazy val impute = (project in file(MODULE_NAME_IMPUTE)).dependsOn(core% "compile->compile;test->test", config)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    enablingCoverageSettings,
    name := MODULE_NAME_IMPUTE,
    description := "Impute the training data"
  )
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)

lazy val split = (project in file(MODULE_NAME_SPLIT)).dependsOn(core% "compile->compile;test->test", config)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    enablingCoverageSettings,
    dockerSettings("split"),
    name := MODULE_NAME_SPLIT,
    description := "Split the dataset into train and test"
  )
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)

lazy val run = (project in file(MODULE_NAME_RUN)).dependsOn(core % "compile->compile;test->test", config, cleanse, encode, feature, impute, split)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    dockerSettings("run"),
    enablingCoverageSettings,
    name := MODULE_NAME_RUN,
    description := "To run the whole setup as a pipeline locally"
  )
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
```

And here is my dockerSettings() function in my build.sbt:

```
def dockerSettings(name: String) = {
  Seq(
    // Always use latest tag
    dockerUpdateLatest := true,

    maintainer  := s"$projectMaintainer",

    // https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk13
    // Remember to use AshScriptPlugin if you are using an alpine based image
    dockerBaseImage := "adoptopenjdk/openjdk13:alpine-slim",

    // If you want to publish to a remote docker repository, uncomment the following:
    //dockerRepository := Some("remote-docker-hostname"),
    Docker / packageName := s"joesan/$projectName-$name",

    // If we're running in a docker container, then export logging volume.
    Docker / defaultLinuxLogsLocation := "/opt/docker/logs",
    dockerExposedVolumes := Seq((Docker / defaultLinuxLogsLocation).value),
    dockerEnvVars := Map(
      "LOG_DIR" -> (Docker / defaultLinuxLogsLocation).value,
    )
  )
}
```

How do I get past this?

Comment: Use a base image that includes bash? Modify your software to use `sh` instead?

Comment: If `sbt-native-packager` is known to work in general, presumably it's your scala project that's trying to invoke bash. If you don't provide the component at fault as part of the question, it's not inside the scope of things we can tell you how to fix.

Comment: What exactly should I add to my question?

Comment: I'm just building my project using the sbt command. I have nevertheless edited my post to include some contents from my build.sbt file

Comment: okay, `alpine-slim` at least is a start -- it tells us why you don't have bash.

Comment: So, there are a few different ways you can fix this. One is to install bash on top of alpine; another is to identify the code that _needs_ bash and try to make it `sh`-compatible

Comment: I would prefer to add bash as dockerCommands in my build.sbt

Comment: You'll want to find the local equivalent to `RUN apk-add --no-cache bash`.

Comment: [info] Step 25/25 : RUN apk-add --no-cache bash
[info]  ---> Running in 8f17c398f76a
[info] /bin/sh: apk-add: not found
[info] Removing intermediate container 8f17c398f76a
[error] The command '/bin/sh -c apk-add --no-cache bash' returned a non-zero code: 127

Comment: There is a `Remember to use AshScriptPlugin` comment in the `build.sbt` file; do you need this plugin?

Comment: ...that said, it looks like adoptopenjdk13 is discontinued, and the replacement jumps direct from 11 to 17 -- but has a great many non-alpine images; any of the ones based on a fatter distro (debian- or RH-derived) will have bash built in.

Comment: Which base image should I use then?

Comment: APK tooling available is very version-dependent. I'll gladly admit that I'm not looking into the details of which exact version of alpine (and thus which version of apk) an ancient, now-unmaintained AdoptOpenJDK image used.

Comment: _shrug_; depends. How dependent are you on having OpenJDK 13? Personally, I'd probably jump to `eclipse-temurin:17-focal` ("focal" being a Debian-family distro release -- I don't recall if it's Debian itself or Ubuntu), but I don't know the technical constraints that led you to choose the one you already have.